# Reliable and simple online IDE for java?

Tags: ide, chromebook

I'm a high school math teacher who just started teaching AP Computer Science A (AKA java) this year. I'm about to start my students on their final projects for the course, but the online sandbox (my students all use chromebooks) crashes under the strain of larger programs. I'd love some recommendations for a solid online IDE that I can have my students set up quickly and easily.

I just spend the last 3 days struggling to get codenvy to work, just to crash and burn when I tested it on user input (I have another stackoverflow question open currently as a last hope). I need something that won't take this much research and work to put into effect.

I've searched for "top online IDEs" and such, but honestly, that's how I got wrapped up in codenvy and lost much work time over the past 3 days.

Any suggestions that would fit my needs? I want my students working in a more legit environment than an online sandbox, but we are stranded with chromebooks.

Thanks,
core

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 IDEs for java  used in the industry

1. Eclipse
2. NetBeans

Netbeans is preferred for the school level project

Comment: The OP was asking about _online_ IDEs, which neither Eclipse or NetBeans are. Also, you're assertion that the two IDEs you mention are the ones used in the industry is both incorrect (consider the market share of IntelliJ for example) and irrelevant.